# Proving that the integrals of two functions are the same if they are equal everywhere except a point

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, integrable-systems

Let $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ be integrable functions over $[a,b]$ and let $∂$ be a point on $[a,b]$. If $f(x) = g(x)$ for all $x≠∂$, then $$\int_a^b f(x)dx=\int_a^b g(x)dx$$

Comment: I am not sure what your conclusion is. There is broken language that makes it difficult to determine what the ending means.

Comment: The demonstration of this resultat depend heavily of the definition of the integral you use.

Comment: I'm assuming you want us to prove this? Also, is this the Riemann integral? Are you assuming the linearity of this integral, because if you are, you can simply consider the integral of the indicator function of $\lbrace \partial \rbrace$: the function that's $1$ at $\partial$ and $0$ elsewhere.

Answer (score 4):

We can look at this from another angle. What we need to show is that $$\int_a^b (f(x)-g(x)) dx = 0.$$ The function $h(x) = f(x)-g(x)$ is zero except at the one point that I will relabel as $p$.

Now suppose that $\delta >0$ and small enough so that $(p-\delta, p+\delta) \subset (a,b)$.

Then $$\int_a^b (f(x) - g(x)) dx = \int_{p-\delta}^{p+\delta} (f(x) - g(x)) dx$$ since $f(x)-g(x)$ is zero outside of $(p-\delta, p+\delta)$.

Moreover: $$\left| \int_{p-\delta}^{p+\delta} (f(x) - g(x)) dx\right| \le  \int_{p-\delta}^{p+\delta} |f(x) - g(x)| dx \le \int_{p-\delta}^{p+\delta} |f(p)-g(p)| dx = 2\delta |f(p)-g(p)|.$$

Now as we let $\delta$ get very small, the quantity on the right tends to zero. Thus $$\int_a^b (f(x) - g(x)) dx = \int_{p-\delta}^{p+\delta} (f(x) - g(x)) dx \to 0$$ as $\delta \to 0$, and we conclude $$\int_a^b (f(x) - g(x)) dx =0.$$